# How to sort an Array by the content of its documents in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

I run the following command from a JavaScript function in the MongoDB-Shell:

```
db._adminCommand( {listDatabases: 1}).databases
```

That gives me:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "local",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
        "empty" : false
    },
    {
        "name" : "time",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
        "empty" : false
    },
    {
        "name" : "event",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
        "empty" : false
    },
    {
        "name" : "admin",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 1,
        "empty" : true
    },
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 1,
        "empty" : true
    }
]
```

Is it somehow possible to sort the documents in that array by their value in the field name?

Finally I'd like to get:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "admin",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 1,
        "empty" : true
    },
    {
        "name" : "event",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
        "empty" : false
    },
    {
        "name" : "local",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
        "empty" : false
    },
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 1,
        "empty" : true
    },
    {
        "name" : "time",
        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
        "empty" : false
    }
]
```

Comment: as neil-lunn referenced the link: run command return a document as result and you cant deal with it like a cursor

You could use javascript to do the job:

    var result = db._adminCommand( {listDatabases: 1}).databases;
    result.sort(function(a,b)
    {
       var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
       var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
       
       //sort string ascending
       if (nameA < nameB)
          return -1 
       if (nameA > nameB)
          return 1
       return 0;
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sort method:

```
db._adminCommand( {listDatabases: 1}).databases.sort(function(item1, item2){return item1.name > item2.name})
```

Comment: databases is a object and not a cursor, you cant use sort() on it

Comment: Yes, you're right. But we can Use Array.sort() since databases is an Array:

db._adminCommand( {listDatabases: 1}).databases.sort(function(item1, item2){return item1.name > item2.name});

Comment: update your answer to your comment and you will get my +1 for sure